# External monitor horizontal lines problem

Tags: 14.04, monitor

I got problem with my external monitor (Dell U2312HM) connected to my laptop (Radeon HD4570). There are appearing some horizontal lines. It is like blinking or flickering, it's actually quite hard to explain, looks like some kind of artifacts. I'm using standard graphic drivers provided by canonical, legacy one from AMD don't wont to install on this version of Ubuntu (14.04).

I tested it with different cables both HDMI and VGA and also on Windows. Problem seems only occur on native resolution (using resolutions below native doesn't show this lines), using Ubuntu and external monitor. And maybe it's worth mentioning, on login screen everything is perfectly fine.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: That is the strangest issue I've ever seen. I noticed when I set screen settings to use both screens - external and laptop then this lines does not appear.

Comment: Well, that's completely my issue! I think it's because they doesn't provide drivers for linux and it's really sad.

Comment: Guys check this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/690945/horizontal-lines-in-ubuntu-15-10?answertab=active#tab-top it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Acer TravelMate 5730 with an ATI Mobility 4570 with resolution of 1920x1080 doing the same. Reducing resolution removes the ínterference but of course, aspect ratio gets affected.

I am still looking for solution.

Comment: All i can think of is re-installing the driver

Comment: @OverCoder check my comment under the main question.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to keep the built-in monitor (laptop's monitor) on but close the lid. No mirroring. There still are some horizontal lines flickering ever once in a while but not as bothersome.

(I have the same series of graphics card and installing AMD's drivers did not work - I could not even log-in to desktop so I had to remove them rightaway.)