# Horizontal lines in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: dell, monitor, 15.10

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 64bit on a Dell Optiplex 780 desktop with a 23 inch monitor, 4 GB of RAM and Intel Duo Core processor. The monitor shows horizontal lines (artifacts) randomly at any place, including on Window texts, so that sometimes they can't be read. I basically can not do anything! I just use a single monitor set up.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I have an identical system and believe I experienced the same/similar issue where certain graphic elements render as interlaced fields with a horizontal offset.

[image: Image of the horizontally shifted pixels]

At first I installed [intel-linux-graphics-installer](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.1), but after reboot the issue remained.

I managed to resolve the issue by

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Comment: This is it! Great thanks you good man! I did the same, installed intel-linux-graphics-installer. Now after using removing command it works!